# How to change a field or add new field in contact us form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I have to change a field of my contact form. For example, there is a field "**telephone**" which I have to replace with "**subject**" field in the contact us page form. Will anyone please tell me how can I make these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open **`form.phtml`** file located at **app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/contacts** folder.
- Then find the following lines of code:

**

```
<li>
    <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

**

and replace it with:

```
<li>
    <label for="subject"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"/>
    </div>
</li>
```

- Now to show this field in contact us mail login to **Admin Panel => System => Transactional Emails** and click **Add New Template** and from the templates drop-down box select **Contact Form**. Then click on **Load Template** button.
- Under template content, find:

> Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}

and replace it with:

> Subject: {{var data.subject}}

- Now go to **System => Configuration** and select **Contacts**. Then under the **Email Options**, select your new template under the **Email Template** drop-down and click on **Save Config** button.

Comment: Thank you so much Mohit. Its Working. You have solved out my query. Thanks once again.

Comment: yeah sure..........

Comment: how to get Attachment field i have tried but file name is get only Please Check screen-short https://prnt.sc/r2yo9s Please Help me